# a question regarding the notation of fourier series expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am kind of confused about the notation here:
[image]

Is it necessary to have the new notation of $S_n(t)$? why can't we keep the same notation of $T_n(t)$ when multiplying the series.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n(t) (cos(nx) + sin(nx)) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n(t) cos(nx) + T_n(t)sin(nx) $?

why is it that the $T_n(t)$ notation in front of sin(nx) has to be changed to $S_n(t)$? is it two different "things"? It is in the part underlined in red. I think they are trying to come up with the coefficients in front of $sin(nx)$ and $cos(nx)$, but why do the manipulation have to differ?

Comment: $sin(nx)$ and $cos(nx)$ are orthogonal so they get their own coefficients.  It's just the same as a general vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is $v = (v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$ and $v_{1} \neq v_{2}$.

Comment: @PeterMorfe Sorry could you elaborate little bit more? could you give a simple example involving 3 to 4 terms of a series to explain what you mean? Sorry for my stupidity, but I don't fully get the explanations.

Comment: Sine and cosine are totally different functions so they get their own coefficients in the expansion.  Just like we write $v = v_{1} i + v_{2} j + v_{3} k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, we don't write $v = v_{1}(i + j) + v_{3} k$.